# how to search hypen and underscore simultaneously within word \w+

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex which will include character between '-' hyphen and '_'Underscore. But the string between these two character might conatin - and _. here is the example

https://regex101.com/r/8vpzqe/1

```
sub-Exp1s07_task-route_learning_acq-test-01_run-14_bold.nii.gz
sub-Exp1s07_task-route_learning_acq-test-01_run-14_bold.nii.gz
sub-Exp1s07_task-map-learning_acq-test-01_run-14_bold.nii.gz
sub-Exp1s07_task-route_learning_acq-test-01_run-14_bold.nii.gz
sub-Exp1s07_task-map_learning_acq-test-01_run-14_bold.nii.gz
sub-Exp1s07_task-map_learning_fmap.nii.gz
sub-Exp1s07_task-map_learning_run-14_fmap.nii.gz
sub-Exp1s07_task-map_work_fmap.nii.gz
```

In the above example i intend to extract output as Exp1s07, routelearning,map_learning, map-learning, route_learning, route-learning, test-01, test01, test_01 instead of a complete string as output which contains above pattern.

With `-\w+_` i am not able to catch - between strings like route-learning.

to explain the larger picture the above example strings have basically a `_key-value_` pair pattern. `sub-Exp1s07_task-map_learning_fmap.nii.gz` Key's - `sub, task, fmap, acq, run values- Exp2s07, map_learning, test-01` etc. 
What i am trying to find is no special character like `-` or `_`in any values. Yes task-XXX is compulsory while acq-XXX, run-XXXare optional. 
route-learning is not going to be common across all examples.

Comment: How will you differentiate between which `-` and `_` to split on ?

Comment: Considering both `_` and `-` as equal, how about: `(?<=[-_])[A-Za-z0-9]+`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8vpzqe/2

Comment: It is only possible if there are known, static parts. Can you be sure that `sub`, `task`, `acq` and `run` will always be there? Then, [it is a piece of cake](https://regex101.com/r/qx30lz/1).

Comment: sub and task will always be there. However acq and run is optional. @Wiktor

Comment: Any example? BTW, `acq` part is crucial. Well, try https://regex101.com/r/qx30lz/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution gives me complete string that contains the pattern. However what i lookg for is, only what is infront of task eg:route-learning  or acq-'XXXXX' ?

Comment: Which example will match `routelearning` or `test01` or `test_01`? Why doesn't `14` match?

Comment: @learnningprogramming: I do not see any problem with matching anything. You seem to only need capured substrings, why not [**grab them with JS code**](https://jsfiddle.net/u3rrrn4a/)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works but one case it doesnt take care? If there's no acq- label and run label it doesnt capture task-*****. I have added the case to my question. Sorry for incomplete explanation before

Comment: @learnningprogramming: BUT `sub-Exp1s07_task-map_learning_fmap.nii.gz` and `sub-Exp1s07_task-map_learning_run-14_fmap.nii.gz` do not contain `test01` part. Is it optional, too? I am afraid the pattern may become unwieldly - see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sbpy0U/1) and [this JS demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u3rrrn4a/1/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Ok to explain the strings have basically a `_key-value_` pair.

`sub-Exp1s07_task-map_learning_fmap.nii.gz`
Key's - sub, task, fmap, acq, run
values- Exp2s07, map_learning, test-01 etc. 

What i am trying to find is no special character like `-` or `_` in any values.

Yes `task-XXX` is compulsory while `acq-XXX`, `run-XXX`are optional

Comment: This task is not possible to solve because you want to split with a delimiter that may be a part of the value you need to get and there is no specific context we can rely on.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew exactly that the challenge i am facing. 

I am thinking now to solve the issue in two steps. First just frame a regex with  sub-***_task-***_[list of all possible values here]. This way i will get taskname and then go for other values

Comment: Which means, only you may provide a valid answer to this question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew trying my best

Answer (score 0):

If you use `/-([A-Za-z0-9]+([-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)_/g` and drop the first and last characters, I think you will get close?

Answer (score -1):

Try `/-(\w+)/g`.

I think this gives you what need

**Update:**

How about `/-(\w{3,})_/g`

*(this makes some assumptions about your numbering convention, but this works for the examples listed above)*

see: https://regex101.com/r/Y2bVY8/1